# Finding the number of Jordan Form Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I'm asked to find the number of Jordan form matrices $A$ with $A^n = O$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $\dim (\text{Null} A^2) = 7, \dim(\text{Null} A^5) = 14$ and
$\dim (\text{Null} A^5 \cap \text{Range} A^5) = 1$ with all the ways the Jordan blocks can be ordered.

I been at this question for majority of the day now. It can be noted that $A^n = O$ means the only eigenvalues of $A$ is 0, so I think I only need to somehow determine how many blocks there are of each size, but I'm struggling with it. So far, I was able to count 36 of such matrices. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're missing some information. What is the size of $A$? What exactly do we mean by the "number of Jordan form matrices" in this context? In particular, the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\&0\\&&0}, \quad \pmatrix{0\\&0&1\\&&0}
$$
are effectively the same Jordan form since they are similar, but should these count as two distinct Jordan forms in this context?

Comment: In other words, when you say "with all the ways the Jordan blocks can be ordered", I don't understand if you mean that these two matrices are considered distinct or that they are considered the same.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $A$ has size $m \times m$ and $m_j$ Jordan blocks of size $j$ for $j = 1,2,3,\dots$. The fact that $\dim [\operatorname{null}(A^5) \cap \operatorname{range}(A^5)] = 1$ tells us that $A$ has exactly one Jordan block with size greater than $5$. In general,
$$
\dim [\operatorname{null}(A^5) \cap \operatorname{range}(A^5)] \geq 
\dim [\operatorname{null}(A) \cap \operatorname{range}(A^5)]
\\ = m_6 + m_7 + \cdots = m - (m_1 + \cdots + m_5),
$$
but the fact that $A$ is nilpotent implies that $\dim \operatorname{range}(A^5) > 0 \implies \dim [\operatorname{null}(A) \cap \operatorname{range}(A^5)] > 0$.

On the other hand, we have
$$
m = m_1 + 2m_2 + 3m_3 + \cdots\\
\dim \operatorname{null}(A^2) = m_1 + 2m_2 + 2m_3 + \cdots 
\\ = m - m_3 - 2m_4 - 3m_5 - \cdots,
\\ \dim \operatorname{null}(A^5) = m_1 + 2m_2 + 3m_3 + 4m_4 + 5m_5 + 5m_6 + \cdots
\\ = m - m_6 - 2m_7 - \cdots.\\
$$
This is all the information that we have about $A$.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Thank you for this. I am now more convinced of my answer 36. I'll upload my solution once I'm officially complete it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sharkeater123 I would be interested in seeing even one matrix that satisfies the criteria given in the problem.

Comment: yeah, I make a program to search for it based on the criteria to see if I can find any and it was able to give me back 36. I'm coming up with something for it tho, hopefully I can do it by end of today.

Comment: I just posted by answer, feel free to check it out. It probably can be shortened a bit by omitting some details.

Comment: @sharkeater finally figured out my mistake; obviously $m$ is not the sum of all $m_j$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A^n = O$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, then for any eigenvector $v$,
$$ 0 = A^nv = A^{n - 1} \lambda v = \dots = \lambda^n v = 0.$$
Hence, $\lambda = 0$ is the only suitable eigenvalue of $A$. This means,
\begin{align*}
    A = \begin{pmatrix}
     J_0^{m_1} & & \\
     & \ddots & \\
     & & J_0^{m_l}
    \end{pmatrix}
   \end{align*}
Now, for any single Jordan block $J = J_0^m$. $J^k = 0$ for $k = m$ since $J$ has
$1$ above the diagonal. For $0 \le k \le m$, we have the $1$'s shifted towards the upper
right corner. So then for $0 \le k \le m$, $\text{Null}(J^k) = \{e_1, \dots, e_k\}$ and Range$(J^k) = \{e_1, \dots, e_{m-k}\}$.
So we have nullity$(J^k) = k$ and rank$(J^k) = m - k$ and $\dim(\text{Null}(J_k) \cap \text{Range}(J^k)) = \min(k, m - k)$.
Noting that for $k > m$, $\dim(\text{Null}(J_k) \cap \text{Range}(J^k)) = 0$. Let $a_j$ be the
number of Jordan blocks of size $m = j$ and $b_j$ be the number of Jordan blocks size $m \ge j$. Then,
$$\text{nullity}(A^k) = a_1 + 2a_2 + 3a_3 + \dots + (k-1)a_{k-1} + kb_k = b_1 + \dots + b_k.$$
From the premise, we know $\text{nullity}(A^2) = 7$ and $\text{nullity}(A^5) = 14$, and so,
$b_1 + b_2 = 7$ and $b_1 + \dots + b_5 = 14\iff b_3 + b_4 + b_5 = 7$. Let $B = \text{Null}(A^5) \cap \text{Range}(A^5)$
and $B_i = \text{Null}(J_0^{m_i})^5 \cap \text{Range}(J_0^{m_i})^5$. Since $\dim(B) = 1$, exactly
one of the Jordan blocks $J'$ must have $\dim(B_i) = 1$ and the rest must have $\dim(B_i) = 0$ and
so for those Jordan blocks with dimension 0, $m_i \le 5$ so $\text{rank}(J_0^{m_i})^5 = 0$. For the
jordan block with dimension 1, we must have $m = 6$ and thus $\text{rank}(A^5) = \sum^l_{i = 1}\text{rank}(J_0^{m_i})^5 = 1$.
By the rank nullity theorem, the size of $A$ is therefore $\text{rank}(A^5) + \text{nullity}(A^5) = 1 + 14 = 15$.
Since exactly one Jordan block has $m = 6$ and $m \le 5$ for all others, we must have $a^6 = 1$ and $a_j = 0$
for all $j > 6$.
Given the above and $b_1 + b_2 = 7 = b_3 + b_4 + b_5$, and that $b_1 \ge b_2$, we have three options,
$(b_1, b_2) \in \{(6,1), (5, 2), (4, 3)\}$.
We can see the only viable choice is $(b_1, b_2) = (4, 3)$ as all other choices results in a invalid partition
of 15. Consider $(6, 1)$, by definition of $a_j$, $b_j$, we have $a_1 = b_1 - b_2$ and so it requires,
$a_1 = 5, a_6 = 1$ and all other $a_j$ to be $0$ and corresponds to the partition $(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6)$.
Similarly, for $(b_1, b_2) = (5, 2)$ results in another invalid partition $(1, 1, 1, 6, 6)$ because
it would make $a_6 = 2\not = 1$.

Now, given $b_1 = 4$ and $b_2 = 3$. We have $a_1 = a_6 = 1$, so there remain two blocks we can
use to partition 15. Hence, the size of these two blocks sums to $15 - 6 - 1 = 8$ and the size
of these two blocks satisfies the condition $b_3 + b_4 + b_5 = 7$. It can be seen that the following
block sizes, $(1, 3, 5, 6)$ and $(1, 4, 4, 6)$ satisfy these requirements. With the first block size
combo having $4!/2$ permutations and $4!$ permutations for the second choice for a total of 36 matrices.